# How do I find the position of an item in a csv file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have this csv file.

```
JFK,John F Kennedy International,5326,5486
ORY,Paris-Orly,629,379
MAD,Adolfo Suarez Madrid-Barajas,1428,1151
AMS,Amsterdam Schiphol,526,489
CAI,Cairo International,3779,3584
```

If there is a way how can find the postion of an item such as `JFK` and and print it out by calling a postition, how do I do it?. If this is not clear : how do i code a print statement that prints `JFK` or `John F Kennedy International`. I'm not that good at python so sorry if this was hard to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a dictionary of the first element mapping to the second element like so:

```
import csv  
with open(fn) as f:  # where fn is the file name
    di={row[0]:row[1] for row in csv.reader(f)}
```

Then it is trivial to get each value from the airport code:

```
>>> di
{'JFK': 'John F Kennedy International', 'ORY': 'Paris-Orly', 'MAD': 'Adolfo Suarez Madrid-Barajas', 'AMS': 'Amsterdam Schiphol', 'CAI': 'Cairo International'}

>>> di['JFK']
'John F Kennedy International'
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv("<path_to_csv_file>")
value = df.loc[df["<column_name>"] == "JFK"]
print(value)
```

I hope I helped!

Answer (score 0):

With python CSV module, you can read all of a csv file row by row:

```
import csv 
with open('your.csv', mode ='r')as file: 
    csvFile = csv.reader(file) 
    x = list(csvFile)
    print(x)
```

> Result

```
[['JFK', 'John F Kennedy International', '5326', '5486'], ['ORY', 'Paris-Orly', '629', '379'], ['MAD', 'Adolfo Suarez Madrid-Barajas', '1428', '1151'], ['AMS', 'Amsterdam Schiphol', '526', '489'], ['CAI', 'Cairo International', '3779', '3584']]
```

You'll notice from the printed result that each rows of your csv is represented as a sublist of the result. So if you print the first element of the first sublist, you should have `JFK`

```
print(x[0][0])
```

> Result

```
JFK
```